# How to create a dynamic range for a row in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My values are in one row and look like that:  [image]

If I add a new month I want to dynamically extend the value range as I want to show the whole progress in a chart.
How can I do that?
I defined a new name and I've tried using the *OFFSET* function but that doesn't really seem to work.
I tried something like that:

```
=OFFSET(supergraph!$U$20; 0; 0; 1; COUNTA(supergraph!$20:$20))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. My interpretation is this: You want the chart to automatically update when you add a new month. Is that correct?

If so, then convert your data into a table (select the data... Insert... Table). Then create your chart. The chart will automatically update when you add data to the next column.

Comment: Correct. If I select the existing data, for instance 25 cols per row and create a table using these 25 columns, then the chart will be updated automatically when I add a 26th column?

Comment: Correct. Create the table, then create the chart. Next time you update and add the 26th column, the chart will automatically update because the Table will recognize your new column should be part of the table.